# C# How to get full path of network file?

Tags: c#, networking

This program is ran from the context menu after right clicking on a pdf file, it simply adds "\ CALL OFF" to the selected file, locally the program works fine, even with spaces. When ran on a file on my nas in which the path contains spaces the output from GetCommandLineArgs stops at the first space.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            textBox1.Text = args[1];
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.Arguments = "-add-text \"/ CALL OFF\" -font \"Helvetica-Bold\" -font-size 14 -pos-left \"194 776\" " + textBox1.Text + " -o out.pdf";
            start.FileName = "cpdf";
            Process.Start(start);
        }
}
```

Comment: string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) all the command line arguments back together, using space as separator, into one string and use that as *the* argument. You'll also need to add double-quotes around the `textBox1.Text` when used in `start.Arguments` to ensure it is received as one:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1).ToArray();
                textBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", args);
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                start.Arguments = "-add-text \"/ CALL OFF\" -font \"Helvetica-Bold\" -font-size 14 -pos-left \"194 776\" "
                                  + "\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"" + " -o out.pdf";
                start.FileName = "cpdf";
                Process.Start(start);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This sorted it out! Just changed String.Join(" ", args) to String.Join(" ",args[1],args[2],args[3]).

Comment: Why did you manually specify the indices. rather than taking all arguments? Be careful with that `args[1], args[2], args[3]`-code, it could throw an exception if there are less than 4 arguments on the command line.

Comment: If I did not specify the indicies I got the full path of the program itself and the selected file, all i wanted was the path to the file that was selected. The path will never change, but I realise this is a less than elegant solution!

Comment: I glanced over the fact that `GetCommandLineArgs` would return the program name in the first element; I've updated the code to skip the first element and work properly with any path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the path name in quotes, you add `\"`:

```
string quoted = "\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"";
```

to get:

```
start.Arguments = "-add-text \"/ CALL OFF\" -font \"Helvetica-Bold\" -font-size 14 -pos-left \"194 776\" \"" + textBox1.Text + "\" -o out.pdf";
```

If you are passing it as a command line argument to the program then you need to quote it there as well:

```
myExe -file "Long path with spaces\file.pdf"
```